# does pthread_setschedparam can change the priority on the fly once the thread is running? how can I change the thread priority for a running thread

Tags: thread, priority

I want to change a thread priority and I have found many examples using `pthread_setschedparam`, but I need to confirm if the priority can be changed on the fly if the thread is already running. In the manual mention the following:

```
   In order for the parameter setting made by
   pthread_attr_setschedparam() to have effect when calling
   pthread_create(3), the caller must use
   pthread_attr_setinheritsched(3) to set the inherit-scheduler
   attribute of the attributes object attr to
   PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED.
```